# Как копировать элемент canvas и вставить в другой div?

Tags: html, jquery

Как копировать элемент canvas и вставить в другой div?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var example = document.getElementById("example1");
  var ctx = example.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, example.width, example.height);

  var canvas = document.getElementById("example2")
  var ventel1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ventel1.beginPath();
  ventel1.arc(205, 70, 7, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ventel1.lineWidth = 10;
  ventel1.moveTo(10, 70);
  ventel1.lineTo(90, 70);
  ventel1.moveTo(90, 0);
  ventel1.lineTo(90, 150);
  ventel1.lineTo(200, 70);
  ventel1.lineTo(90, 0);
  ventel1.moveTo(212, 70);
  ventel1.lineTo(300, 70);
  ventel1.stroke();

  $(".item").draggable({
    revert: true
  });

  $(".item").mouseup(function(e, ui) {
    var cord = $(this).position();
    xpos = cord.left;
    ypos = cord.top;
    console.log("xpos:" + xpos, "ypos:" + ypos);

    var x, y, yClick, xClick, xpos, ypos;
    var position = $('#tabs-2').position();
    x = position.left;
    y = position.top;
    var h = $('#tabs-2').height();
    var w = $('#tabs-2').width();

    if (xpos > x && xpos < x + w && ypos > y && ypos < y + h) {
      console.log("попадает");
      $(this).draggable({
        revert: false
      });
      $(this).draggable({
        containment: "parent"
      });
      $(this).prependTo('#tabs-2');
    }

  });



});
```

```css
.item {} #drag1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#drag2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 57px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#tabs-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 150px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs-1">
  <div id="drag1" class="item">
    <canvas height='70' width='130' id='example1'></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="drag2" class="item">
    <canvas height='70' width='130' id='example2'></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">

</div>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

как можно копировать черный прямоугольник или линию и вставить его копию в другое поле(tabs-2) (и была возможность перемещения копированного элемента в родительском объекте) c помощью jquery

Comment: Думаю тебе нужно выбрать что то из этого https://habrahabr.ru/post/140286/
либо сделать итеративность в конвасе сложно. Сам сейчас мучаюсь,но у меня еще все сложнее )